# Can I enable autosave when running Offline mode on Heroes 6?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

For some reason I can't get autosave working in offline mode.

I gave a try to online mode but after being kicked out from game without saving just when I finished final battle I have decided to play offline. I usually just Alt-Tab and leave my pc to sleep. I have also read a lot about conflux non-reliability.

Any suggestion? Either way - enabling autosave in offline mode or not being kicked out from game when waking up or loosing connection for longer when online?

thanks

**EDIT**

I have restarted the game and PC and it is all working now. Although only with one Autosave but better than nothing or "connecting" to conflux.

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, perhaps you'd care to post your solution as an answer or delete the question entirely? Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restarted the game and PC and it is all working now.
From what I can see only one autosave is available in offline mode. It still seems better "connecting" to conflux.