# What's the Difference between HOMM VI Online and Offline mode?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

What are the differences to the two modes? If I play offline do I get less features than had I played online? The only feature I can think of that I'll be losing are the Conflux orbs, but are there others?

Comment: You'll lose a lot of angry cursing, as you won't have to deal with your network connection dropping out during a long battle and having the game exit to the desktop.  :(

Comment: Haha. Fortunately, I've played 40+ hours now and that hasn't happened to me yet. XD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one's made the attempt to differentiate the two, I decided to try it out for myself.

### Features Missing from Offline Mode

- **Conflux Orbs**
- **Dynasty Weapons**

  - You can still claim them in the Campaign but they're disabled in the inventory screen
- **Dynasty Traits**

  - Option appears at the beginning of the game
- **Hero Choices**

  - When playing skirmish you get a very limited pool for hero choices (1 might hero, 1 magic hero per race)
- **Daily/Weekly Autosaves**

  - It still autosaves on occassion (before a hero fight), but you [lose the regular interval autosaves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32866/can-i-enable-autosave-when-running-offline-mode-on-heroes-6/33031#33031)