# Are there ways to play Heroes 6 with an intermittent connection?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

How often does Heroes 6 need to be online? I have a consistent internet connection but since it's just one of those USB sticks, the connection isn't reliable. I'm always connected but at times my ping shoots up and I get unceremoniously ejected to the Main Menu. Is there any way to make Heroes check conflux every few minutes or so instead of having to stay connected 100% of the time?

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing online, you must be constantly online.  There are currently no settings to control the online connection, so any network hiccups will cause the game to exit the main menu.

With an intermittent connection, you are pretty much limited to playing offline, which will allow you to play without the annoying game "exits", but which does remove some of the fancier bits of the game.  See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33315/whats-the-difference-between-homm-vi-online-and-offline-mode) for more information.